# Diagonal power series is holonomic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, formal-power-series

Let $F(x,y):= \sum_{n,m} a_{n,m}x^m y^{n}$. Where $m,n$ are postive integers. My question to start with is that is there any basic operation that is integration, differential or substituting $x,y$ with function of $g(x),g(y)$ such that we extract 
$DF(x,y):=\sum_{n} a_{n,n}x^n y^n$ ?

I feel the following is true but cannot prove. If $F(x,y)$ is a solution to a linear differential equation with over the field $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$ then so does $DF(x,y)$.

The usual closure properties for solution to differetial equation hold true such as sum, products etc. So if I can extract the $DF(x,y)$ from $F(x,y)$ with those operation then I could prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Hint:** Using the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series we can extract the diagonal from $F(x,y)$ via
>   \begin{align*}
> G(t)=[y^0]F\left(\frac{t}{y},y\right)=\sum_{n} a_{n,n}t^n
> \end{align*}

Related information can be found in *[this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.04526.pdf)*. Interesting information about diagonalisation is also given in *[this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104832/a-diagonal-operation-on-power-series/221089#221089)*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the paper they assume $F(x,y)$ to be rational and proves that Diag $F(x,y)$ is algebraic. Is some extension of the result know that is if $F(x,y)$ is holonomic/ $\partial$ finite multivariable then DiagF(x,y) as well ?

Comment: @GGT: You're welcome. I have no more information about this aspect. I've added a reference which might be useful. Maybe *[this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037704279090042X)* by D. Zeilberger contains useful info.